# spring3 build error

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a web application using struts2 and spring 3. for configuring spring I have added needed libraries in the project using build path in eclipse and also in tomcat.
I added the listener in web.xml also, but when I want to run the application this error appears:
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
I googled too much but nothing happen..
some one told me to be sure to add spring-web.jar in both application lib and tomacat, but nothing chang..
please help

classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"    path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre6">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/hibernate"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/asm-attrs.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/asm.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/DateConverter.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/freemarker-2.3.13.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hsqldb.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/imaging.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/iText-2.1.7.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jasperreports-4.5.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ocrs12.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-2.6.11.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/orai18n.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/simplecaptcha-1.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-1.4-GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xwork-2.1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/spring"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the spring jar at runtime. Are you using a build tool like maven?

Comment: No, I am using Run as>Run on server in eclipse

Comment: Can you provide the content of the .classpath file of your project ?

Comment: if it would be possible, I can attach the snapshot. But I think it's not possible!

Comment: In eclipse, go to the navigator tab, click on your .classpath file and just copy/paste the content in your question. It's plain text.

Comment: Are you sure your eclipse project build path includes the necessary spring jars ?

Comment: I have added all classpath in question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23849/discussion-between-ngs-and-ddewaele)

Comment: I can see you have created Eclipse User Libraries, spring and hibernate. Can you update the question with the content of the User Library jars that you have included.

Comment: both of them, I tried.. user library and jar files added to project and no one was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using maven instead of manually fiddling around the eclipse classpath, if you have liberty to do so. Here are the simple steps that you can follow:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=test -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This will generate required maven project structure. Then edit the pom.xml file as below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Build the project:

```
mvn clean package
```

And generate eclipse configuration source files:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

This steps are sufficient to create project structure which has required libraries in classpath with sources attached.

Finally you can import the project in Eclipse.

```
File > Import > General > Existing project into Workspace > Select the project directory
```

You can download and install maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 1):

I often get this problem `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`  when eclipse does not correct puplish the application to the tomcat server (this happens often when I start eclipse the first time in a day or after some larger svn checkout)

I my case it helps to perform an sequence of action (and always wait with the next step until the step before is complete finished!!)

- first to refresh the project (F5), then
- have a clean project build (project/clean),
- refresh the project again (F5), then
- clean the server
- publish the project to the server

Answer (score 0):

i see u use the eclipse wtp plugin for run web app, then You can find the expansion web app in the filesystem, and check the lib directory have spring.jar, 
also u can see this [My application does not see ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670157/my-application-does-not-see-contextloaderlistener)