# My application does not see ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have an app using spring 3.0.3 . all needed jar have been added but when I run it in eclipse this error happen:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

I opened the org.springframework.web-sources-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar and I can see the ContextLoader.java file!!!!
here is the web.xml configurations:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml     


    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: applicationContext.xml should be in your classpath, can you check it from your project build path.

Comment: you mean I have to add applicationContext.xml in java build path?

Comment: @NGSyes you should add it to your build path

Comment: `org.springframework.web-sources-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar` contains the sources not the binaries. You need the jar without the `-sources` prefix to be in your `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you *running* your app? If using tomcat then make sure the required jars are present on either tomcat's  lib folder or create a directory called `lib`  in `WEB-INF` directory and put all the spring jar's inside that.

Placing the jars on classpath is ok for development in eclipse but for running the app your container (tomcat etc) should know about it and the only way to do that is to place jars in `lib` directory.